# ira_laser_tools not working

Tags: ros, roslaunch, multiple, node, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am trying to use the ira_laser_tools.

I did the following:

```
cd catkin ws/src
git clone https://github.com/iralabdisco/ira laser tools
```

Then compile the package (make sure you have PCL [4] installed):

```
cd ..
catkin make
```

and its compiling but when I am trying to run the launch file it says:

> ERROR: cannot launch node of type [ira_laser_tools/laserscan_multi_merger]: can't locate node [laserscan_multi_merger] in package  [ira_laser_tools]

I really want to use this package but I have no freaking idea what the problem is.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215359/ira_laser_tools-not-working/) by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2015-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You did source the `setup.bash` of the `devel` space of the workspace?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) on 2015-08-06**:
I am so sorry, you saved my ass. thanks mate

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2020-05-12**:
I've also had this issue but nothing is fixed when I do: `~/catkin_ws/devel$ source setup.bash`. Any ideas?